# Optimizing n-queens in Haskell

Tags: performance, haskell, optimization, n-queens

This code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}


module Main where

import Data.Bits
import Data.Word
import Control.Monad
import System.CPUTime
import Data.List

-- The Damenproblem.
-- Wiki: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damenproblem
main :: IO ()
main = do
  start <- getCPUTime
  print $ dame 14
  end <- getCPUTime
  print $ "Needed " ++ (show ((fromIntegral (end - start)) / (10^12))) ++ " Seconds"

type BitState = (Word64, Word64, Word64)

dame :: Int -> Int
dame max = foldl' (+) 0 $ map fn row
  where fn x = recur (max - 2) $ nextState (x, x, x)
        recur !depth !state = foldl' (+) 0 $ flip map row $ getPossible depth (getStateVal state) state
        getPossible depth !stateVal state bit
          | (bit .&. stateVal) > 0 = 0
          | depth == 0 = 1
          | otherwise = recur (depth - 1) (nextState (addBitToState bit state))
        row = take max $ iterate moveLeft 1

getStateVal :: BitState -> Word64
getStateVal (l, r, c) = l .|. r .|. c

addBitToState :: Word64 -> BitState -> BitState
addBitToState l (ol, or, oc) = (ol .|. l, or .|. l, oc .|. l)

nextState :: BitState -> BitState
nextState (l, r, c) = (moveLeft l, moveRight r, c)

moveRight :: Word64 -> Word64
moveRight x = shiftR x 1

moveLeft :: Word64 -> Word64
moveLeft x = shift x 1
```

needs about 60 seconds to execute. If i enable compiler optimisation with `-O2`, it takes about 7 seconds. `-O1` is faster and takes about 5 seconds.
Tested a java version of this code, with for-loops in place of mapped lists, it takes about 1s (!). Been trying my hardest to optimize yet none of the tips i found online helped more than half a second. Please help

Edit: Java version:

```
public class Queens{
    static int getQueens(){
        int res = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            int pos = 1 << i;
            res += run(pos << 1, pos >> 1, pos, N - 2);
        }
        return res;
    }

    static int run(long diagR, long diagL, long mid, int depth) {
        long valid = mid | diagL | diagR;
        int resBuffer = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            int pos = 1 << i;
            if ((valid & pos) > 0) {
                continue;
            }
            if (depth == 0) {
                resBuffer++;
                continue;
            }
            long n_mid = mid | pos;
            long n_diagL = (diagL >> 1) | (pos >> 1);
            long n_diagR = (diagR << 1) | (pos << 1);

            resBuffer += run(n_diagR, n_diagL, n_mid, depth - 1);
        }
        return resBuffer;
    }
}
```

Edit: Running on windows with ghc 8.4.1 on an i5 650 with 3.2GHz.

Comment: Can you share the Java version? Usually it is very hard to completely implement the very same program in two programming languages (especially in case two languages have different paradigmas).

Comment: Can not reproduce. Here (GHC 8.4.1) I get 40s without optimization, 2.7s with -O3.

Comment: You are right, sorry my bad there must be an error in my stack setup. Nevermind, why is the performance so low compared with the java version?

Comment: General comment: turning on `-Wall` and fixing issues (and observing DRY in general) often results in better performance, as well as better code (`map (fn x) ... where fn max x = ...` is quite confusing for instance, and I wondered if you'd made an implementation error)

Comment: Looking at core, I suspect the main issue is that your lists haven't fused away (you can look for `[]`, `:` in the core dump). I wonder if you can rewrite `recur` and `getPossibleDepth` in some way so as to be a "good producer". If not you might try rewriting without using lists but instead an accumulator (though I'm not suggesting that's a satisfying answer)

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your algorithm is correct (I haven't verified this), I was able to get consistently 900ms (faster than the Java implementation!). `-O2` and `-O3` were both comparable on my machine.

Notable changes: (EDIT: Most important change: switch from `List` to `Vector`) Switched to GHC 8.4.1, used strictness liberally, `BitState` is now a strict 3-tuple
Using `Vector`s is important to achieve better speed - in my opinion you can't achieve comparable speed with just linked lists, even with fusion. The Unboxed Vector is important because you know the Vector will always be of `Word64`s or `Int`s.

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}

module Main (main) where

import Data.Bits ((.&.), (.|.), shiftR, shift)
import Data.Vector.Unboxed (Vector)
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as Vector
import Data.Word (Word64)
import Prelude hiding (max, sum)
import System.CPUTime (getCPUTime)

--
-- The Damenproblem.
-- Wiki: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damenproblem
main :: IO ()
main = do
  start <- getCPUTime
  print $ dame 14
  end <- getCPUTime
  print $ "Needed " ++ (show ((fromIntegral (end - start)) / (10^12))) ++ " Seconds"

data BitState = BitState !Word64 !Word64 !Word64

bmap :: (Word64 -> Word64) -> BitState -> BitState
bmap f (BitState x y z) = BitState (f x) (f y) (f z)
{-# INLINE bmap #-}

bfold :: (Word64 -> Word64 -> Word64) -> BitState -> Word64
bfold f (BitState x y z) = x `f` y `f` z 
{-# INLINE bfold #-}

singleton :: Word64 -> BitState
singleton !x = BitState x x x
{-# INLINE singleton #-}

dame :: Int -> Int
dame !x = sumWith fn row
  where
    fn !x' = recur (x - 2) $ nextState $ singleton x'
    getPossible !depth !stateVal !state !bit
      | (bit .&. stateVal) > 0 = 0
      | depth == 0 = 1
      | otherwise = recur (depth - 1) (nextState (addBitToState bit state))
    recur !depth !state = sumWith (getPossible depth (getStateVal state) state) row
    !row = Vector.iterateN x moveLeft 1

sumWith :: (Vector.Unbox a, Vector.Unbox b, Num b) => (a -> b) -> Vector a -> b
sumWith f as = Vector.sum $ Vector.map f as
{-# INLINE sumWith #-}

getStateVal :: BitState -> Word64
getStateVal !b = bfold (.|.) b

addBitToState :: Word64 -> BitState -> BitState
addBitToState !l !b = bmap (.|. l) b

nextState :: BitState -> BitState
nextState !(BitState l r c) = BitState (moveLeft l) (moveRight r) c

moveRight :: Word64 -> Word64
moveRight !x = shiftR x 1
{-# INLINE moveRight #-}

moveLeft :: Word64 -> Word64
moveLeft !x = shift x 1
{-# INLINE moveLeft #-}
```

I checked the core with `ghc dame.hs -O2 -fforce-recomp -ddump-simpl -dsuppress-all`, and it looked pretty good (i.e. everything unboxed, loops looked good). I was concerned that the partial application of `getPossible` might be a problem, but it turned out to not be. I feel like if I understood the algorithm better it might be possible to write in a better/more efficient way, however I'm not too concerned - this still manages to beat the Java implementation.

Comment: On my machine with `-O2` i get 2.8s which is twice as fast as my code - thanks for that - but the java solution runs in 1.75s.

Comment: Hm, I just ran the Java code on my machine - seems that the Java is faster on my machine as well, but by a much smaller factor. The Java runs about 50-75 more milliseconds to run, always hitting between 825 and 850.

Comment: But, having a factor of 3x speed on the Haskell implementation on my machine versus yours. I have two questions. 1) Which version of GHC are you running, and 2) What are the specs of your machine?

Comment: In addition to your suggestions: `-fflvm` makes the code run an extra 32% faster on my machine.

Comment: Running on windows with ghc 8.4.1 on an i5 650 with 3.2GHz. Will try llvm when installed

Comment: With llvm it runs in 1.8 seconds on my machine what is comparable to java. I only do not really understand why it is so hard to write performant haskell whereas in java everything runs fast by default. Logic in Haskell is so beautiful but this is a pita

Comment: @devsteff, do you have a link explaining the algorithm you're using? Also, the optimisations we've made thus far aren't very difficult or advanced. The only one I say that would be a bit of a stretch is resorting to the LLVM backend.

Comment: @chessai Seems to be mostly the same: [Click](https://jgpettibone.github.io/bitwise-n-queens/)

Comment: One thing to consider that may affect how you perceive Haskell optimisations - lazy-by-default languages like Haskell can perform worse when doing dense numerical computations - which is why using strictness and making sure things get unboxed is really important. Also, I will read through the algorithm and see if there's something I can pick out.